# I’m using RN-fetchblob for downloading files and Pictures but the swipeable does not change language when i change it on my IOS device

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-fetch-blob, rn-fetch-blob

Swipe-able of RN-fetchBlob

[image: 1]

'Picture is attached above'

Problem: problem is that it does not change the language when i change my language on my IOS device in settings and as well as on my Simulator.
Actually my app is in two languages English and Spanish so i want that my React native Fetch Blob should change the language of the Swipe-able when i change in my phone setting

i search inside the whole library files but that doesn’t help.

Comment: are you sure it is `rn-fetch-blob` functionality? From my point of view, this is a share component. How do you call this share window?